ValidationError: 1 validation error for GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings model field required (type=value_error.missing)
I am trying to integrate the GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings from the langchain_google_genai library into my Streamlit application. However, I am encountering a ValidationError related to missing fields when I attempt to create a GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings object. Here’s the error message I am seeing:
ValidationError: 1 validation error for GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings
model field required (type=value_error.missing)
Traceback:
File "E:\Project_Gen_AI\chat-with-website\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 600, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "E:\Project_Gen_AI\src\demo2.py", line 84, in <module>
    st.session_state.vector_store = get_vectorstore_from_url(website_URL)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\Project_Gen_AI\src\demo2.py", line 31, in get_vectorstore_from_url
    vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(document_chunks, GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY))
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\Project_Gen_AI\chat-with-website\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\v1\main.py", line 341, in __init__
    raise validation_error

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

import streamlit as st
from langchain_core.messages import AIMessage, HumanMessage
from langchain_community.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_google_genai import GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings, ChatGoogleGenerativeAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain.chains import create_history_aware_retriever, create_retrieval_chain
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain

load_dotenv()

GOOGLE_API_KEY = os.getenv("GOOGLE_API_KEY")

def get_response(user_query):
    return "First, please build me"

def get_vectorstore_from_url(url):
    loader = WebBaseLoader(url)
    document = loader.load()

    # Split the document into chunks using the RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter()
    document_chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(document)

    # Create a vectorstore from the chunks
    vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(document_chunks, GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY))

    return vectorstore

def get_context_retriever_chains(vectorstore):
    llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)

    retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()

    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.format_messages([
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),
        ("user", "{input}"),
        ("user", "Given the above conversation, generate a search query to look up in order to get information relevant to the conversation")
    ])

    retriever_chain = create_history_aware_retriever(llm, retriever, prompt)

    return retriever_chain

def get_conversational_rag_chain(retriever_chain):
    llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)

    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.format_messages([
        ("system", "Answer the user's questions based on the below context:\n\n{context}\n"),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),
        ("user", "{input}")
    ])

    stuff_documents_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, prompt)

    return create_retrieval_chain(retriever_chain, stuff_documents_chain)

# For the interface
st.set_page_config(page_title="Chat-with-website", page_icon="")
st.title("Chat with website")

# App Sidebar
with st.sidebar:
    st.header("Settings")
    website_URL = st.text_input("Website url")

# Check if the website URL is provided
if website_URL is None or website_URL == "":
    st.info("Please enter a website url")

# Load documents from the provided URL using the WebBaseLoader
else:
    # Session state
    if "chat_history" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.chat_history = [
            AIMessage(content="Hello, I am a bot. How can I help you"),
        ]
    if "vector_store" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.vector_store = get_vectorstore_from_url(website_URL)

    retriever_chain = get_context_retriever_chains(st.session_state.vector_store)

    conversation_rag_chain = get_conversational_rag_chain(retriever_chain)

    # CHAT HISTORY / AI response to User Input
    user_query = st.chat_input("Type your message here... ")
    if user_query is not None and user_query != "":
        response = conversation_rag_chain.invoke({
            "chat_history": st.session_state.chat_history,
            "input": user_query
        })
        st.write(response)
        st.session_state.chat_history.append(HumanMessage(content=user_query))
        st.session_state.chat_history.append(AIMessage(content=response))

    # Iterate through the chat history stored in the session state
    for message in st.session_state.chat_history:
        # Check if the message is an instance of AIMessage
        if isinstance(message, AIMessage):
            # Display the AI message in the chat interface
            with st.chat_message("AI"):
                st.write(message.content)
        # Check if the message is an instance of HumanMessage
        elif isinstance(message, HumanMessage):
            # Display the Human message in the chat interface
            with st.chat_message("Human"):
                st.write(message.content)

I suspect that I might be missing some required parameters when initializing GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings, but I can't find any documentation or examples that show what those parameters should be.
What could be causing this validation error, and how can I resolve it?
